# Animation e Transition no CSS Juntos Não Funcionam

Tags: javascript, css

Estou escrevendo o código abaixo e não está funcionando a parte do `transition`.

A classe `.menu-fixed` eu aplico via javascript. A animação quando abre o site. A animação funciona, mas quando eu aplico a classe que contém o `transition` não funciona.

Eles não funcionam juntos num mesmo elemento ?

### CSS

```
            &.fundo-menu{
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: -500px;
                opacity: 0;
                margin: auto;
                width: auto;
                animation-name: LogoTorcaneDesce;
                animation-timing-function: ease;
                animation-duration: 2s;
                animation-delay: 0.2s;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                transition: all 0.8s ease;
                &.menu-fixed{
                    width: 230px;
                }
            }
```

### JS

```
    var MenuHeaderBox = $("header#header, nav.menu, .fundo-menu, .logo-menu");
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 300){
            MenuHeaderBox.addClass('menu-fixed');
        }else{
            MenuHeaderBox.removeClass('menu-fixed');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema. A transição não funciona quando determino um valor `auto` na propriedade.

No meu caso tinha um `width: auto`. Troquei pelo valor real da imagem e o `transition` funcionou.

Acredito que isso é para todos os casos.